# In eclipse,when doing source jump in the class JpaTransactionManager,some methods are invalid

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, spring-data-jpa

I find when the version of the spring framework is above 4,some method do not support to jump into, when trying to jump into using F3,there is a warning on the left corner 'Current text selection cannot be opened in an editor.'.I had tried in spring 3.X and spring 4.X,the former worked well.Could anyone help with the problem?(For example:In class JpaTransactionManager,line 310 the method setDataSource do not support to jump into)

Comment: Are you sure they exist?

Comment: @AleksandrM,In fact  the methods are in the same class of JpaTransactionManager,which belongs to the spring-orm-xxx.RELEASE.jar.(Example:The method setDataSource in afterPropertiesSet do not support to jump into)